# If I logout of Kimono, will my APIs 'in progress' STOP

Tags: kimono

I have an API currently running (manual crawl), i.e. with status 'in progress', and according to my estimation, it's going to take 10 hours to complete.

I am therefore asking myself whether the API will continue to run on Kimono's servers if I logout of Kimono's website.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, after your API generated you can close browser's tab or even logout, this is also valid for crawls in progress,